# Node.js: Signature verification (PS256) succeeds in Node.js but fails in jwt.io debugger

Tags: node.js, jwt, rsa, auth0

I wrote a test script with which I'm signing and then verifying a JWT with the PS256 algorithm.

My code verifies the JWT successfully, but the verification fails in the [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) debugger.

I'm using `jws@3.2.1`.

**This happens only when using the PS256 algorithm, not when using, for instance, RS256.**

Am I doing anything wrong?

I generated my keys with:

```sh
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key2.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key2.pem -out public_key2.pem
```

You can try my code on repl.it: https://repl.it/@SamArtuso/Nodejs-Signature-verification-PS256-succeeds-in-Nodejs

Code:

```js
const { join } = require('path');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const jws = require('jws');

const ALG = 'PS256';

/**********
 * SIGNING
 **********/

const PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = join(__dirname, './keys/private_key2.pem');

const privateKey = readFileSync(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH).toString();

const payload = {
  foo: 'bar',
};

const token = jws.sign({
  header: { alg: ALG },
  payload,
  privateKey,
})

console.log('Token:');
console.log(token);

/************
 * VERIFYING
 ************/

const PUBLIC_KEY_PATH = join(__dirname, './keys/public_key2.pem');

const publicKey = readFileSync(PUBLIC_KEY_PATH).toString();

const result = jws.verify(token, ALG, publicKey);
if (result) {
  console.log('Verification successful.');
} else {
  console.error('Verification failed.');
}
```

Private key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz0fAg//VfX3XUbzJOfdC
bblOIT0/Yjw/5mHlnb1E25Ddoj6YOiwwAwZ7c/CPQs04QpIB5g0IYePUMwDjYh38
h4Sk+hxyAUu/MBln4RPbnhbZL9fcYrLxSUwzuiJZRhTIoqI/AJLzicGmPuWSkhRt
9ldIDGoJTUjUzoeSiug7MYHR9inzM5+rhcCZL7M9asD4iDbv66rzkDziCiQmzRwT
oP0r4T1gUhBQwvQJC5t2o4RgHJ0pVotCoFBc+4h7lEerOBi3ZHONLgKKGBMRFrGc
qAck9fLV5Z9oTwLxNQLWtj0m7Sx7sLzELeL82YvNCuAV6joqrzTKNQNWk6EkJ5js
LQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**Edit:** Clarifications on how to reproduce my issue.

1. Run my script with: `npm init -f && npm install jws && node test.js`
2. The script will output the token and `Verification successful.`
3. Copy and paste the token in the "Encoded" field on jwt.io
4. Copy and paste the public key in the "Public key or certificate" field.
5. A red "Invalid Signature" message appears at the bottom.

The below is an example of the token my script will generate. Bear in mind that PS256 has a *probabilistic* rather than *deterministic* signature, so the signature will be different every time you run the script.

```
eyJhbGciOiJQUzI1NiJ9.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIifQ.Rn6i-94ovuKOVRc2jzLVS40MpMmBkIfkyvF56JK3tM8wvg-DW943NNbXf01bhRdyoUj0A73NSQtz0kB4WfXN1uAH1omzNr0ww-iTfC23AX0OcjbsE7CcDz_ZQWWOzwEGGFVfV9ez5yn1pKRYVdFaKqApk3irP-ej_WGrrJfgeZVs683lNk0WjKOYhj6vsryuz52c0OEJ0UmYy7hSSfL38jgL6bdE0awg2DgiaU6qszZEkMjSnugoMobeAUUyOiXHsR79NryuhCQko-I9P1vKd1dEA3zM1iut5sW5FwB8K9Fi49gaQy0zHk72txJvUWdxW5ns0Svft3qLke5XMuqm2g
```

Comment: Please do not mark this question as duplicate. What makes it unique is that it is specific to the PS256 algorithm.

Comment: so you read the potential duplicate questions and answers, right?! But you don't tell us, what exactly you did on jwt.io, because in most cases people just forget to upload the key on jwt.io. Would be easier if you would tell us exactly what you did there.

Comment: Yes, I did go through the potential duplicates and none matches my question.

I copied my token and pasted it on jwt.io. I also pasted my public key in the corresponding field on jwt.io. I'll update the text of the question to reflect this.

Anybody should be able to reproduce what I did.

Comment: then please also show your token in the question, so that people can try.

Comment: OK, I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to copy and paste your token, your public key and your private key to the debugger of jwt.io. Here are my findings:

1. If you only paste the token, the token is decoded correctly, but the signature can't be verified (which is obvious).
2. If you then paste the *public key* (which should be enough to verify the signature), the signature still can't be verified. This is strange
3. If you then paste the *private key* as well (which should not be required to verify the signature), the signature is shown to be valid.

So, apparently things come down to the question why the token's signature can be verified only if the private key is given…

This led me to the assumption that somehow the private key and the public key don't match each other. So I tried to regenerate (or better, extract) the public key from the private key you have given and compare that one to the public key you suggested. So, I pasted your private key into a file named `privateKey.pem`, and ran the following command:

```
$ openssl rsa -in privateKey.pem -pubout
```

This gave me the following public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz0fAg//VfX3XUbzJOfdC
bblOIT0/Yjw/5mHlnb1E25Ddoj6YOiwwAwZ7c/CPQs04QpIB5g0IYePUMwDjYh38
h4Sk+hxyAUu/MBln4RPbnhbZL9fcYrLxSUwzuiJZRhTIoqI/AJLzicGmPuWSkhRt
9ldIDGoJTUjUzoeSiug7MYHR9inzM5+rhcCZL7M9asD4iDbv66rzkDziCiQmzRwT
oP0r4T1gUhBQwvQJC5t2o4RgHJ0pVotCoFBc+4h7lEerOBi3ZHONLgKKGBMRFrGc
qAck9fLV5Z9oTwLxNQLWtj0m7Sx7sLzELeL82YvNCuAV6joqrzTKNQNWk6EkJ5js
LQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Unfortunately, this is the very same public key that you provided, too, so we can tick this thought off from our list.

So, I started to search the web and found [this blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/jwt-io-and-jwt-debugger-extension-updates/) by Auth0 where they describe the introduction of support for `PS*` algorithms, but according to the documentation, everything should work as expected. Hmmm, more strange

So, the next thing I tried was to encrypt things using jwt.io's debugger, using the decoded values of your token, with algorithm `PS256` and your provided private key. This brought me to this token:

eyJhbGciOiJQUzI1NiJ9.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIifQ.wzkD7q5lH_qJw_V6DJLk72TDqpzA05KN3XHfEFOeAQgCriodoOLrgQ-p3ifIzK525puiV1hnXQuJ-6TEZRqiO8dqlPWQJbG1mLdTTx7ZwdUKsDjY6CMsmsskU8eVrzfaSDVmGvbjaWKq1_KGvtk4vMT0Z9m_YhUjD_SDVbCaZReEbzxta4APM7dMQ5mRFzD03JTwe05_AqayrfXdTungeBEJcMB0tY_4FjWiKbBZOpyQLebzPJ69VgpQFGvf6fPuKT6_3LTEHPrRNFL05OYpgRvayh3pEAF297aSCQ_SFi9slqDdVKkor-q8UDO-zM7J952uCkr7NkXV0Loq62_gMg

If you paste *this* token into jwt.io's debugger, and use *your* public key, then the signature is valid. So, basically `PS256` seems to work with jwt.io, but for whatever reason not for your token…

This finally leads me to the thought that maybe Node.js and jwt.io do use different ways to run the `PS256` algorithm. Of course, since it's a standard, both should work the same way, but apparently they don't. I don't know who of both does it wrong, or if it's fine that both work in different ways, as I never had to deal with `PS256` before.

I'm very sorry that I have no better answer for you here, but I guess that the only way to find out the real reason is to debug into Node.js's crypto code, and to have a look at jwt.io's source code (which is not publicly available, as far as I know).

From my point of view, what you do is correct, and I'd rather guess that this is a bug in either Node.js or jwt.io, or in both

PS: After having written this answer, I found [this issue](https://github.com/brianloveswords/node-jws/issues/85), and I guess the original author is you (aren't you?), and the reply there basically comes to the same conclusion, that it's a problem of the website. So maybe this actually is the best answer you can get.

Comment: Actually, jwt.io *is* open-source. Its repository is [here](https://github.com/jsonwebtoken/jsonwebtoken.github.io). The JWT verification code is [in this file](https://github.com/jsonwebtoken/jsonwebtoken.github.io/blob/master/src/editor/jwt.js); it seems to just be a wrapper around `node-jose`.

Comment: Good catch. I'll try to run it locally and see if I can find any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem using openssl API in my c++ app. Apparently my app could produce PS256 signature and pass its validation by itself, but on jwt.io validator signature validation failed. So after some research I discovered that openssl on my platform automatically set wrong salt length for PS256 signature algorithm. For PS256 it should be 32. When I set salt length to 32 manually - signatures produced by app passed validation on jwt.io.

P.S.: When You post private key in jwt.io (PS256 alg) payload is automatically re-signed, and if You have set right public key - signature is verified as valid. JWT io can validate signature basing on public key only(when You have right signature for the payload).

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you are copying the keys correctly.

https://jwt.io/ requires you to copy the including the `BEGIN` and `END` tag lines

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

[image]

Comment: I did what you suggested, but that didn't solve my issue.

Comment: @kYuZz That's probably because the signature of your token is wrong... check my screenshot and compare that with your token, you will find the signature is different.

Comment: The PS256 algorithm outputs a probabilistic signature, i.e. it creates a different signature every time you sign the same payload. That is why our signatures are different. I believe that my issue has to do with a bug in the `jws` package. Please see: https://github.com/brianloveswords/node-jws/issues/85#issuecomment-466012814

Comment: @Sohail if you paste **only public key** (not private key), then it will show signature invalid. Please remember that only public key should be needed to verify a token.